# How to change the matches in add_rewrite_rule

Tags: rewrite-rules

One of the examples using `add_rewrite_rule` function in wordpress is

```
add_rewrite_rule('^nutrition/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?','index.php?page_id=12&food=$matches[1]&variety=$matches[2]','top');
```

I can understand where matches[1] is and where matches[2] is, but is there any way to change these matches, something like:

```
add_rewrite_rule('^nutrition/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?','index.php?page_id=12&food=' . f1($matches[1]) . '&variety=' . f2($matches[2]),'top');
```

Where `f1` is a function of `matches[1]` and `f2` is a function of `matches[2]`

Thank you very much.

Edit 1:

This is a very general question with the objective to understand wordpress add_rewrite rule. One example of f1 and f2 function is

```
function f1($string) {
if (strpos($string, '/america/')) {$string .= '-1';}
esleif (strpos($string, '/england/')) {$string .= '-2';}
return $string;
}
```

f2 was a similar function to f1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rewrite rules don't call functions like you're asking. WordPress is far more flexible than that, because you might want to run your code at any one of an unlimited set of points in the processing of the page and not be restricted to that *one specific moment* in the code when the rewrite rule is processed.

Taking it back a step, rewrite rules are meant to work just like `$_GET` does, where you can pass data through the URL, like `domain.com/?id=123`. The difference is that the `id=` is determined by the rewrite rule, so you can have a pretty url like `domain.com/123/`. Oftentimes we'll keep the `id` in the URL, e.g. `domain.com/id/123/` to avoid conflicts with other URL structures, but that's not important for the sake of this answer.

Using your example, say you had a rewrite rule for nations, and you wanted your URLs to look like `/nation/america/` or `/nation/england/`. Here is an example rewrite rule for this:

`add_rewrite_rule( '^nation/([^/]*)/?', 'index.php?nation=$matches[1]' );`

To use this information, you can pretty much hook into any [action](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference) or [filter](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference) after `parse_query`. That's the first action available after the query vars are set, so it's the first action where you can use [get_query_var](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_query_var). Here's an example:

```
function wpse_99414_get_nation() {
    if ( $nation = get_query_var( 'nation' ) ) {
        # This is the equivalent to your f1 function
        # $nation will either be 'america', 'england', or whatever else
        # process it however you need!
    }
}
add_action( 'parse_query', 'wpse_99414_get_nation' );
```

Lastly, note that in order to use a custom query var like how we used `nation`, you need to register it. Here's an example of doing that:

```
function wpse_99414_query_vars( $qv ) {
    $qv[] = 'nation';
    return $qv;
}
add_filter( 'query_vars', 'wpse_99414_query_vars' );
```

Comment: I think this is an excellent answer and very detail explanation. Thank you very much :)

Comment: @aye Happy to help!

Answer (score 0):

The function arguments are computed at the time of function call, so when rewrite rule is being registered rather than when it is being matched and used.

You will need to do processing on matched values at different point in code.

Comment: so do you know where to edit the code?

Comment: @aye how would I? `f1()` and `f2()` give me nothing about what you are trying to achieve, what it depend on and what would be right place in load process to apply them. :)

Comment: Hi Rarst, i have edited the question. Actually i'd like to know where to include the function `f1` and `f2`