# Editing the variables in a custom URL

Tags: permalinks, url-rewriting

I have an existing page in a custom theme that expects a URL in this form: `/story?user=1` but I'd like to be able to use better URLs as well, eg: `/story/username`.

I've tried to add a rewrite rule in functions.php as below, which gets me half-way, allowing URLs like `/story/1`:

```
function my_custom_url() {
    add_rewrite_rule('story/([^/]+)/?','index.php?pagename=story&user=$matches[1]','top');
}

add_action( 'init', 'my_custom_url' );
```

However I'd still like to use the username in the URL. To allow that, I was expecting to change the rewrite rule to this:

```
add_rewrite_rule('story/([^/]+)/?','index.php?pagename=story&user='.get_user_id($matches[1]),'top');
```

Where `get_user_id()` is a function that returns the id for a specified username, but that doesn't seem to work (as tested with the Rewrite Analyzer plugin).

[This answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/101556) pointed me towards the `parse_query` hook, so I tried something like this (together with the original rewrite rule):

```
function my_query_var() {
    if ($user = get_query_var('user')) {
        $id = get_user_id($user);
        global $wp_query;
        $wp_query->set('user',$id);
    }
}

add_action('parse_query','my_query_var');
```

However that doesn't seem to work either; Rewrite Analyzer shows that the 'user' portion of the URL remains set to whatever was typed after 'story' in the address bar, rather than the result of `get_user_id()`.

Any ideas what I should be doing instead? Thanks!

**Edit**

Probably worth mentioning that I'm registering the `user` variable as the below:

```
function register_query_var($query_vars) {
    $query_vars[] = 'user';
    return $query_vars;
}

add_filter('query_vars','register_query_var');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMHO easiest way to do the trick is use a simple rewrite rule, and demand the logic to the page, e.g.

```
function my_custom_url() {
  add_rewrite_rule('story/([^/]+)/?','index.php?pagename=story&user=$matches[1]','top');
}    
add_action( 'init', 'my_custom_url' );
```

After that in page where you need the user id use:

```
$userqv = get_query_var('user');
$user = is_numerical( $userqv ) ? $userqv : get_user_id( $userqv );
```

In this way the `$user` variable will be set to whatever is after the url if it's a number, and if something not numerical is used in url, it will treated as an username and the user id is get accordingly.

Comment: Thanks! I was trying to avoid editing the original page's PHP, but I agree this is probably more straight-forward. I'd still be interested to see anyone's solutions to changing the URL without editing the page's code though.